# DB2 SQL0104N An unexpected token "?" was found following ""

Tags: c#, sql, db2, prepared-statement, oledb

I am trying to run a db2 sql statement using the oledb command function in c#. Actually i am running another sql queries at the same way but I am getting following error when executing this query.

> [DB2] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "?" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  <INTEGER>.  SQLSTATE=42601

```
string sql = @"EXPLAIN PLAN SET QUERYNO =? FOR ? commit;"

 using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con))
        {                    
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@queryNo", queryNo);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@query", query);

                    var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

If I use it with string concatenation it runs correctly but string concatenation can lead to SQL Injection problems. So I need to use parameterized query. How can I fix it?

```
string sqlPattern = "EXPLAIN PLAN SET QUERYNO ={0} FOR {1}commit;";
string sql = string.Format(sqlPattern, queryNo, query);
```

Answer (score 1):

[EXPLAIN statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-explain):

**FOR explainable-sql-statement**
...
The *explainable-sql-statement* must be a valid SQL statement that could be prepared and executed independently of the EXPLAIN statement. **It cannot be a statement name or host variable**.

You can use parameter markers in a statement string (like in an ordinary prepared statement), but you can't use a parameter marker for a whole statement (like for ordinary prepared statement).
If you are afraid of injections, just concatenate the 'EXPLAIN ... ' string constant with a statement text passed by user to construct a final statement.